# End to End BDD Testing , putting Web and Mobile native app automation is single framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, appium-android, appium-ios

what would be best approach and framework to be designed for integration test case.
Is it possible to create single framework where and action done from UI is need to be validated on mobile native app and vice versa.
Eg : On Web Application I had enable one menu for user , now I need to verify whether that menu is visible for specific user on mobile app.

I wanted use selenium and appium for same , or is there any other way I can do this , what will be best practice , a sample code will be much helpful.

Comment: No answer for this query yet?? This helps lots of people like me who are after the open-source functional automation framework for both mobile and web apps.